# font-family is not working in my css file

Tags: css

I'm working with css in my mockup, and I need to put a specific font, in this case the font as the name of `Roboto`, but when I put that font on css, the font doesn't change

Here's the code:

```
.field__item p{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color:red;
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1- Go to Google fonts website here: https://fonts.google.com/

2- Search for the font `Roboto` on search bar

3- Select the sizes you want

4- And then you have on your right a code like this:
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

5- Then after paste that code into your file, the font should work